How would I use a VM to allow automation with pyautogui
I have a problem with my current program I use MAMP for local host storage with SQL and I use pyautogui with pygetwindow to press and click buttons, fill in forms, and such. However, I want to be able to use my current computer without it getting in the way, so I tried using a VM and RDP with Microsoft Azure however I run into the FAILSAFE error because the VM is using the same mouse, and when I close the RDP it doesn't shut down the VM, but it seems to make all my python programs crash as I'm using a discord bot too and that shuts down when I exit the RDP connection. I don't know what type of solution people have used for getting two mouses with a VM, also I want to be able to shutdown my computer and not have the RDP connection just shutdown because that causes my discord bot to crash since the python program on the VM is closed. Also, I don't really know docker, but is this something better suited for containers instead of a VM maybe?
